# What is role of nucleation centre in the formation of ice?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, water, phase-transition

Water must be impure so that the impurities can act as [nucleation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleation) centre for ice to form. What is role of nucleation centre? Why can not ice form with some nucleation centre?

**About existing (and currently accepted) answer** It says that a dust particle can "fool" the water molecules, but it does not make clear how does it actually do it? How on earth is it capable of attracting water molecules any better than another water molecule. I think that the existing answer pushes the mechanism under the carpet. Can someone improve the details?

Comment: I’ve forms in pure water as well. It is a statistical question based on the temperature relative to the melting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nucleation center "fools" the liquid water molecules by appearing as if it were a tiny chunk of solid ice, to which water molecules will readily attach themselves and freeze into position.

Water will freeze in the absence of physical nucleation sites like grains of dust because sooner or later, a small number of the water molecules in the supercooled liquid will randomly rattle themselves into the right position and spontaneously form a nucleus on their own.

Answer (score 0):

> "fool" the water molecules,

The accepted answer is correct but does not go into details.

Why ice forms? because the lattice locations that the H2O will occupy have a binding that once formed , will be retained turning water into solid. Here is a link with [ice lattice shapes .](http://www.iceandclimate.nbi.ku.dk/research/flowofice/ice_crystal_structure/)

Water , as most substances has a [phase diagram](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/cheminter/chapter/phase-diagram-for-water/), solid, liquid, gas, which is a function of temperature. ice is the solid form.

When the temperature is high the molecules cannot be caught in the lattice positions. As the temperature falls, below the freezing point in the diagram, there will still be a lot of molecules with high enough kinetic energy, due to the statistical nature of [temperature,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/temper.html) , to disturb continually the setting up of the lattice. If one introduces a lattice, i.e. the regularity in the potentials seen in the link, with a bit of dust of a solid lattice, then water molecules can attach to the seed, protected from random scatters, and start extending and building up the hexagonal lattice.

As the temperature drops the water will freeze anyway, even without seeds. The seeds will be small lattices that manage to coalesce despite the scatters from higher energy moleculs.